# 2 tableViews in 2 different UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have 2 tables in my application, both in different views and both have different classes. Both classes have almost identical code, but only 1 of them works.

The one that doesn't work is my URLViewController.

URLViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface URLViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSArray * tableData;
    NSArray * tableSubtitles;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray * tableData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray * tableSubtitles;

@end
```

URLViewController.m

```
#import "URLViewController.h"

@interface URLViewController ()

@end

@implementation URLViewController
@synthesize tableData, tableSubtitles;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.jpg"]]];

    tableData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Location 1", @"Location 2", @"Location 3", @"Location 4", @"Location 5", @"Location 6", @"Location 7", @"Location 8", @"Location 9", @"Location 10", @"Location 11", @"Location 12", @"Location 13", @"Location 14", nil];

    tableSubtitles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"http://www.google.fi/", @"http://www.google.fi/", @"http://www.google.fi/", @"http://www.google.fi/", @"http://www.google.fi/", @"http://www.google.fi/", @"http://www.google.fi/", @"http://www.google.fi/", @"http://www.google.fi/", @"http://www.google.fi/", @"http://www.google.fi/", @"http://www.google.fi/", @"http://www.google.fi/", @"http://www.google.fi/", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = nil;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Listaus"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Listaus"];
    }

    //cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    //cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [tableSubtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

All I get right now is just blank white page.

How come does the other class with almost identical code work, but this one not? The one that works is the one I created at first.

Comment: did you set delegate and datasource for both tableviews?

Comment: have you added table to viewController's view using xib file?

Comment: Where did you set delegate and datasource? Where did you reloaded your table?

Comment: I didn't do either of those (datasource or delegate). I assumed I could simply copy paste most of the code and have it work like that. I honestly have no idea how to do either of those anyway. @sanjaymathad Yes, I have done that.

Comment: you should start by reading the documentation.

Comment: ok,then set the dataSource and delegate either in xib file or in viewDidLoad using tableView's reference and call [tableView reloadData] at last line of ViewDidLoad

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_ui_elements_tableview.htm flow this tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you declared like below in your .h file.

```
@interface DisplayViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

[image: Also Check if you have set delegate and datasource to tableview at xib like below]

Answer (score 0):

Reload the table in the end of `viewDidLoad` method. `tableData` does not contain anything at the time the table is made which is before the `viewDidLoad` method. So, reload the table using `reloadData` method.
Also, in your `viewDidLoad` method, declare `self` as the delegate and datasource of the table.